# My Flutter App keeps crashing on my Android Kitkat 4.4.4 tablet

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i am trying to test my app on my old android tablet that runs android KitKat 4.4.4 but every time I try to run the flutter app in vs code, it's able to build the debug Apk then when installing and the app launches it crashes with the message "unfortunately app has stopped"
i tried using this command "Flutter run enable software rendering" hoping it will be able to run my app but the same problem occurs, don't know what to do now, how can I run it on my tablet?

this is my app/build.gradle

```
 defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.weepay_pos"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
                    multiDexEnabled true

    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error logs on your vscode console?

Comment: What is your `minSdkVersion` in your `app/build.gradle` ?

Comment: minSdkVersion 16 is my minSdkVersion

Comment: it doesnt start logging when it crashes, I don't think t runs at all, so no logs in the debug console, when installing, the app loads then crashes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My Flutter App keeps crashing on my Android Kitkat 4.4.4 tablet when installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65400206/my-flutter-app-keeps-crashing-on-my-android-kitkat-4-4-4-tablet-when-installing)