# My Flutter App keeps crashing on my Android Kitkat 4.4.4 tablet when installing

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i am trying to test my app on my old android tablet that runs android KitKat 4.4.4 but every time I try to run the flutter app in vs code, it's able to build the debug Apk then when installing and the app launches it crashes with the message "unfortunately app has stopped" i tried using this command "Flutter run enable software rendering" hoping it will be able to run my app but the same problem occurs, don't know what to do now, how can I run it on my tablet?

this is my app/build.gradle

```
 defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.weepay_pos"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
                    multiDexEnabled true

    }
```

here is the logcat while running  the app

```
 D/LogBase ( 4545): data_app_crash@1608618948143.txt
D/LogFilter( 4545): LogSummaryInfo: {apkName, com.example.weepay_pos }{version, 1.0.0 }{reason, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.weepay_pos-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.weepay_pos-1, /vendor/lib, /data/cust/lib, /system/lib]] }{stack, at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5087) }{stackFuzzy, at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5087),at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4673),at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4613),at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:141),at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298),at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102),at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136),at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5336),at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method),at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515),at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871),at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687),at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method),Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.weepay_pos-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.weepay_pos-1, /vendor/lib, /data/cust/lib, /system/lib]],at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56),at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497),at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457),at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5072) }
V/WindowAnimator( 1374): Window{423be380 u0 NavigationBar}: wasAnimating=false, nowAnimating=false
V/WindowAnimator( 1374): Window{422fda88 u0 StatusBar}: wasAnimating=false, nowAnimating=false
```

Comment: What is your `minSdkVersion` ?

Comment: If there is a dialog with a message like "unfortunately app has stopped", there will be something in Logcat as well - please add the crash log to the question

Comment: i added the logcat to my question, please view

Comment: minSdkVersion 16

Comment: Do you solve this issue @mordecai?

Comment: @mordecai are you using any plugins that require minSdkVersion to be > 16? and can you also share the list of packages you are using?